LLVM-C not compiling
I'm on Pop os linux, I have download llvm-project and built llvm with cmake. When I went through the libraries and was looking for LLVM-C it was not there. I tried rebuilding it and could not find it. How can I get LLVM-C on Pop os. Thank you

--git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project
mkdir build--
cd build
cmake -G "Ninja" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang" -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_C_DYLIB=ON -DLLVM_ENABLE_BINDINGS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../llvm
ninja
make
sudo ninja install
sudo make install
sudo apt install build-essential cmake ninja-build
try these steps, let me know if it works, please note i used "--" to separate each commands

@maxis112 I tried running the commands, but it says libllvm-c can only be generated on darwin.

The message about it "only being generated on Darwin" (which refers to macOS) suggests that the build process or configuration might be designed specifically for macOS, and you're likely trying to build or install this on a different platform (such as Linux or Windows).
ensure u are using the right source code.

The flag LLVM_BUILD_LLVM_C_DYLIB is used to build LLVM as a dynamic lib, but on certain platforms like GNU/Linux or Windows, this feature might be either unsupported or handled differently.
You can try removing this flag: -----
cmake -G "Ninja" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang" -DLLVM_ENABLE_BINDINGS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../llvm

@maxis112 I used git to pull the source code from the main branch. I also tried removing the flag, but it didn't generate.
